# how to changed text color to grey when the button is disabled, and when it's enabled is blue?

Tags: android, user-interface

This is my interface. The Buttons "Save" is disabled. Because I changed the background, So The disabled Button became the same color with Enabled buttons .

[image]

**HERE IS MY SOME EXAMPLE XML's CODE**

```
<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
    android:background="#BFBFBF"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:id="@+id/Db_New"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="NEW" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
    android:background="#BFBFBF"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:id="@+id/Db_Save"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:text=   "SAVE" />
```

Because I use these to change the background and text color.

```
style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
android:background="#BFBFBF"
android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
```

I'm thinking how to change the "Save" text color to grey when it's disabled, and when It's enabled It will be the blue color...

Comment: maybe you could use this https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource

Comment: does it only for text color? what's about background color? @rmanalo

Comment: from what I remember, you could change each attribute separately. if you just want to change the text color, then just set that. if you want to change the background color, then set that. if you want to change the text color and the background color at same time, then set them both at the same time

Comment: but there is only `android:color`, But doesn't has `android:background_color`

Comment: oh. sorry. it's been so long since i've used it so I don't really remember everything.

Comment: noted. Thank you @rmanalo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the text color to be different you could use the first thing I posted, the color state list resource.

If you want to change the background color of the button per state, you could follow this https://blog.stylingandroid.com/state-list-drawables/. Don't mind the first parts because it just talks about the button creation. Start on the part where it explains about button states.